# How to copy data from ADF to Synapse with special character("Ã") in one of the fields without errors or record rejection

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I have a scenario where I copy data from Azure storage account(CSV - Pipe delimited source file) to Azure Synapse using ADF Copy utility. However the pipeline is failing because three of the records has special character **"Ã"** in one of the character field. Tried different encodings UTF-8,UTF-16 and Windows-1252, but none of them resolved my issue. I have also tried direct Copy utility(**Copy into ""**) within Azure Synapse and getting the same error. I am able to manually insert those three records using "**Insert into** " statement.

Is there a better way to handle this without Manual inserts through something like doing pre conversion of that character before copy or through any available settings in ADF?

Comment: Are you sure the original data contains a “Ã”? It’s rather rare character. It’s much more frequent if UTF-8 encoded data is incorrectly treated as ISO-8851-1 (or similar encoding).

Comment: Yes original dataset contained latin A character. After changing the source dataset settings for escape character and quoted character with UTF-8 encoding this issue got resolved. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Please re-check the **format settings for the source csv dataset** as given in this [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-data-warehouse?tabs=data-factory#direct-copy-by-using-copy-statement).

I reproduced this in my environment, and I am able to copy the csv data with special characters into Synapse with default UTF-8 encoding.

**This is my source csv with special characters:**

[image]

I have created a table named `mytable` in Synapse.

```
create  table mytable (
firstname VARCHAR(32),
lastname VARCHAR(32)
)
WITH
(
DISTRIBUTION = HASH (firstname),
CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
)
GO
```

In the source give the format settings as per the above documentation.

[image]

Here I have used **copy command** to copy. If you want to create table automatically, you can enable it in the sink.

[image]

**Copied data in Synapse table:**

[image]

Comment: Hi , the logic worked but it's showing as "?" Within the database. Is there anyway to fix it or should I change any synapse config settings?